# Formato numerico en python

Tags: python

soy nuevo con Python y estoy desarrollando un script para baja información en tiempo real de Binance y registrarla en una hoja de Excel. El problema es que el código me crea la hoja de Excel almacenando los valores numéricos como texto, y esto no he podido solucionarlo.
Este es el codigo, agradezco cualquier comentario:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime

# Define los parámetros de la API
params = {
    'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
    'interval': '30m',
    'startTime': '1696032000000',
    'endTime': '1735603200000'
}

# Hacer una solicitud a la API de Binance
response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines', params=params)

# Evaluar si la respuesta sea exitosa
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()  # Suponiendo que la API devuelve JSON

    # Crear un DataFrame vacío
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fecha', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volumen Coin', 'Volumen Par', 'Trades', 'Taker buy base asset volume', 'Taker buy quote asset volume'])

    # escribir los datos en las siguientes filas
    for item in data:
        row_data = {
            'Fecha': datetime.fromtimestamp(item[0]/1000).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'),  # Fecha
            'Open': "{:,.2f}".format(float(item[1])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Open
            'High': "{:,.2f}".format(float(item[2])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # High
            'Low': "{:,.2f}".format(float(item[3])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Low
            'Close': "{:,.2f}".format(float(item[4])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Close
            'Volumen Coin': "{:,.3f}".format(float(item[5])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Volumen Coin
            'Volumen Par': "{:,.3f}".format(float(item[7])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Volumen Par
            'Trades': "{:,.3f}".format(float(item[8])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Trades
            'Taker buy base asset volume': "{:,.3f}".format(float(item[9])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", "."),  # Taker buy base asset volume
            'Taker buy quote asset volume': "{:,.3f}".format(float(item[10])).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")  # Taker buy quote asset volume
        }
        df = df.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)

    # Guardar el DataFrame en un archivo de Excel en una nueva hoja sin modificar las existentes.
    df.to_excel('C:\\xxxxx\\xxxx\\Datos Historicos Binance\\Binance API Tiempo Real.xlsx', sheet_name='A30', index=False)
```

Comment: Hola José, al momento que les das formato los estás convirtiendo a cadenas de texto.

Comment: Hola Jose, te los guarda como texto porque tu mismo haces la conversion a `str` con `str.format(float(...))`. Python nunca hace conversiones implícitas de datos, por lo que las claves del diccionario son objetos `str`, esas columnas del dataframe seguirán siendo de tipo `object` (objeto `str` de python) y al convertir a excel lo harán como cadenas que son. Si quieres que sean `floats` no debes hacer la conversion a `str`,

Comment: Supongo que lo que buscas es dar el formato que quieres a los datos en el excel, pero una cosa es el dato y su tipo (float) y otra muy diferente como se muestran al usuario. Tus datos tiene que seguir siendo float en todo momento, el formato lo debes establecer para cada columna del excel, si mal no recuerdo usando xlsxwriter como engine se puede hacer ¿como quieres el formato? ¿punto como separador de miles y coma para la parte decimal?

Comment: Gracias a todos por los comentarios, voy a tomar en cuenta lo dicho